# Extra construction when using placement new with a storage class

Tags: c++, placement-new

In a situation where I want to avoid dynamic memory allocations, I'm replacing the new operator with a process that essentially uses the memory of some statically allocated object (the `Storage` class below). You can see a minimum working example below:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct Object { 
  Object() { std::cout << "Creating a new object\n"; } 
  static void *operator new(size_t);
  static void operator delete(void *p);
};

static struct { 
  Object where;
  bool allocated = false;
} Storage; // 1

void *Object::operator new(size_t) { 
  assert(!Storage.allocated);
  auto p = ::new (&Storage.where) Object; // 2
  Storage.allocated = true;
  
  return p;
}

void Object::operator delete(void *p) { 
  assert(Storage.allocated);
  static_cast<Object *>(p)->~Object();
  Storage.allocated = false;
}

int main() { Object *obj = new Object; } // 3
```

My question has to do with **the number of calls to the constructor**. When I [run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73f2b712c9a39e78) the above program, I expect to call the constructor twice (marked as 1 and 2 in the comments above) but the output I get is:

> Creating a new object
>
> Creating a new object
>
> Creating a new object

Why is the constructor called thrice? I'd only expect constructor calls, by the static object and the call to placement new. I tried tracing the code with gdb, but it makes no sense to me, since position `//3` is `where` the third call to the constructor originates.

The reason I want to know is because a case has emerged, where this extra constructor call causes unwanted side-effects; up until now, this extra call was unnoticed.

Comment: @Jarod42 The numbered comments are where the breakpoints tell me the call originates. One is from static initialization, one in placement new; the question is: **what is the third?**

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's ```#0  Object::Object (this=0x555555756160 <Storage>) at placement.cpp:7 
#1  0x0000555555554a4f in main () at placement.cpp:31``` (line 7 is the `cout` and line 31 is the single line in `main`)

Comment: Shouldn't the placement new operator not(!) call placement new for the object?
So the first is `Storage::where`, the second is in the `operator new` and the third in the `main`-function.

Comment: It's a misunderstanding about what the `operator new` function should do: It should only *allocate memory*, not construct objects. Therefore it shouldn't do the placement-new.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, you're right! There are so many examples online that show the constructor being called besides placement new, that it's easy to misunderstand the situation

Comment: On a side note (since your question is already answered), you don't need to  have an Object allocated statically, replace it with "char buf[sizeof(Object)];" and constructor is called only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object *obj = new Object;` does two things:

1. Allocates memory by calling `operator new`
2. Calls the constructor.

Your `operator new` calls the constructor as well, so the constructor is called twice by this statement (and once for the global variable initialization).

Note that `delete` is the same. `delete obj;` does two things:

1. Calls the destructor.
2. Deallocates memory by calling `operator delete`

Your `operator delete` shouldn't call the destructor either, because then the destructor is called twice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but the whole point of the pattern is to not actually allocate memory at runtime

Comment: Wow, thanks for the extra bug fix, I might have to change the selected answer now

Answer (score 6):

For some odd reason, your `operator new` calls the constructor when it should just allocate memory. This means that the call to `new` winds up calling the constructor of `Object` twice. There is one call in `operator new` and another call in `main`.

You probably want this:

```
void *Object::operator new(size_t) { 
  assert(!Storage.allocated);
  Storage.allocated = true;
  return reinterpret_cast<void *> (&Storage.where);
}
```

Imagine if the constructor took an integer parameter and the line in `main` looked like this:

```
Object *obj = new Object(7);
```

How would `operator new` know how to properly construct the object? That's not where you're supposed to do that!